# Should we rename the tag statetree to state-tree?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, moderation, retag-request

As follow-up of [this question](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/87), should we rename the tag [statetree](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statetree) to [state-tree](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-tree)?

- It's two words and should be seperated by a dash.

[Here is how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197731/226837).

Comment: Makes sense to me :)

Comment: I agree with this change.

Comment: Might consider state-trie if it's to be renamed.

Comment: @indeed. recently noticed it's `state-trie`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this has been done (status-completed tag), I'm answering this question so it doesn't appear on the list of unanswered questions. If someone can accept this answer it then it will disappear from that list!

Comment: good idea, will accept it now.