# Should we break up the mining tag like Bitcoin SE?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tagging

Murch♦ from Bitcoin Stackexchange is [currently dissolving](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/734/6441) the [mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining) tag. He is working hard on retagging roughly 1400 questions!

Here are his recommendations for Ethereum Stackexchange: [Good Tags now save a lot of work later!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/87)

Should we learn from that example and dissolve the [mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining) too, before we end up going through hundrets of questions later rather than only around 50 by now?

Possible tags could be:

- [miner-configuration](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miner-configuration)
  Collects questions about configuration of mining hardware, and optimizing the software settings of mining rigs.
- [mining-hardware](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-hardware)
  Collects questions about mining rigs, cpus, gpus, fpgas, and asic miners, as well as the production, and producers of such.
- [mining-pools](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-pools)
  Questions about organizing groups to collaboratively work on block creation.
- [mining-profitability](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-profitability)
  Collects questions about the economics of mining operations.
- [mining-theory](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-theory)
  Questions about the function, the reason for, and the underlying concepts of mining.
- [cpu-mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cpu-mining)
  Questions about using CPUs for mining.
- [gpu-mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpu-mining)
  Collects questions about mining setups on basis of GPUs.
- [pool-payout-methods](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pool-payout-methods)
  Questions about sharing revenue in mining pools.
- [shares](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shares)
  Shares refers to a method for accounting mining pool contributions. It does not cover company shares.
- [solo-mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solo-mining)
  refers to mining by yourself, not organized in a mining-pool
- [mining-software](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-software)
  General questions about mining software.
- [mining-setup](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-setup)
  Is used for questions concerned with the physical setup of mining hardware.
- [miner-configuration](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miner-configuration)
  Collects questions about configuring and optimizing the software settings on mining rigs.
- [mining-technical-details](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mining-technical-details)
  Is used for questions on the technical process of building a block header, and what gets hashed in mining.

Does that also apply to Ethereum related mining questions? Do we need maybe less tags? Or more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At the current point with less than 100 answers tagged with 'mining' it should not be broken down yet. We should re-evaluate this at a later time.